# Pandas: set sliding window to iterate over rows and apply a function

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `DataFrame`in `pandas`:

```
[A]             [measure]
17442.77000     32.792658
17442.8         name1
17442.95100     32.792658
--
--
17517.49200     37.648482
17517.5         name2
17518.29600     37.648482
--
--
17565.77600     38.287118
17565.8         name3
17565.88800     38.287118
--
--
17596.93700     41.203340
17597.2         name4
17597.29700     41.203340
--
--
17602.16400     41.477979
17602.5         name5
17602.83900     41.612774
--
--
17618.16400     42.479890
17618.4         name6
17618.71100     42.681591
```

I'd like to iterate over every three rows and apply a function that:

```
f(x)= df.iloc[0,1]+(df.iloc[2,1]-df.loc[0,1])*((df.iloc[1,0]-df.iloc[0,0])/(df.iloc[2,0]-df.iloc[0,0])).
```

Ideally I'd like to return the result in a dictionary format so I could have:

```
Results={"name1": f(x), "name2": f(x),...}
```

Any hints about how to set my sliding windows in pandas is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this should work:

```
def f(x):
    return df.iloc[0,1]+(df.iloc[2,1]-df.iloc[0,1])*((df.iloc[1,0]-df.iloc[0,0])/(df.iloc[2,0]-df.iloc[0,0]))
```

Here you apply rolling with a `window=3` and `min_periods=1` with a step of 3 using `[[::3]]`

```
a = df.rolling(window=3, min_periods=1).apply(f)[::3].reset_index(drop=True)
```

After you save the strings of the column `measurement` to a list `s`

```
s = list(i for i in df['measure'] if isinstance(i, basestring))
```

And assign `s` as key of the dictionary `d`

```
d = a.T.to_dict('list')
for index, k in enumerate(list(s)):
    d[k] = d[index]
    del d[index]
```

Comment: Thank you Joe for your detailed explanation. The `df.rolling` is exactly what I was looking for!